# What happens when declaring a column NOT NULL in SQLite db in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When you define a column in an android SQLite database, what happens when you say define a field as TEXT NOT NULL. I know that it may not be null, but lets say you insert a value to only one column or field, does the rest of the columns default to an empty string "" if they are declared TEXT NOT NULL ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to supply a value for each of the NOT NULL columns.
OR provide a default value: `..., myField TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', ...`

For reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_constraints.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you did not specify default values for those columns it will just thrown an `Exception`. `NULL` in SQLite represents absense of value, therefore it's not equal to an empty string.

Comment: In my case, I did not add the option NOT NULL. When I added a single field, the rest of the columns received NULL as their values or I guess it just didnt change the default value I guess. Essentially, I would like them all to default to an empty string.

Comment: @Janpan then you just should add `DEFAULT` clause in table schema (for column description) to specify something different from `NULL`